# N-elements byte array to integer conversion (little/big endian and signed/unsigned)

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to come up with a function to convert byte arrays to their integer representation, using both
endianness, and with a signed/unsigned option.

```
enum class ByteOrder {
    LITTLE,
    BIG
}

fun ByteArray.toInt(byteOrder: ByteOrder = LITTLE, signed: Boolean = true): Int {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot convert an empty byte array")
    }

    val negative = signed &&
            (this[if (byteOrder == LITTLE) size - 1 else 0]).toInt() and 0b1000000 != 0

    if (!negative) {
        return absoluteToInt(byteOrder)
    }

    // The number is stored as two's complement.
    // Thus we invert each byte and then sum 1 to obtain the absolute value
    val negatedBytes = ByteArray(size)

    for ((i, byte) in withIndex()) {
        negatedBytes[i] = byte.inv()
    }

    return -(negatedBytes.absoluteToInt(byteOrder) + 1)
}

private fun ByteArray.absoluteToInt(byteOrder: ByteOrder): Int {
    var result = 0
    var shift = 8 * (size - 1)
    val range =
        if (byteOrder == LITTLE) {
            size - 1 downTo 0
        } else {
            0 until size
        }

    for (i in range) {
        result = this[i].toInt() and 0b11111111 shl shift or result
        shift -= 8
    }

    return result
}
```

You can submit a byte array of arbitrary size. Example:

```
val bytes: ByteArray = 9388608.toBytes() // Little endian, 4 elements
val intVal: Int = bytes.toInt() // Little endian
```

What's your opinion? Can this be done in a better way?

Comment: Explicitly separating the logic for converting signed vs unsigned would help with readability I think

Comment: @TedBrownlow the unsigned switch is basically `signed &&`, so there is no logic to separate imho.